# How to pass Virtually Anything To A Function In C++ (or C)?

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers

I need to pass something like a pointer that takes anything as a function parameter. You know, something without any predefined type or a type that can take anything  like this:

```
 void MyFunc( *pointer );
```

And then use it like:

```
char * x = "YAY!";
MyFunc(x);

int y = 10;
MyFunc(&y);

MyObj *b = new MyObj();
MyFunc(b);
```

And I don't want to use templates because I am mostly using C in my project.
Is there **anything** that can be used here except a function macro?

Comment: Does "anything" include pointers to functions?  Pointers to members?

Comment: I am not sure, but I may need those too in the later stages of developing my library. Especially pointers to functions.

Comment: "Anything" sounds like YAGNI (at least not right now).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain't_gonna_need_it

Comment: Why are you asking about C++ when you don't want to use C++?

Comment: Because I would need to use C++ if the solution is only in C++. Therfore I welcome C++ answers too.

Comment: I suggest you ask the real question, what is you design goal, people can suggest better decisions than a function taking anything.

Comment: Well , I am making a small signals - slots - connections library to be used with my gui toolkit. So that I can get rid of the Ugly WNDPROC. I need these pointers for the connections.

Comment: Types in C and C++ are there to help you. They force you to think of your design and protect you from yourself. If you pass different types to your function, you'd have to handle the complexity of deciding what to do in `switch` or similar of your mega-function. Several different functions with a well-defined interface let you just handle the case one-by-one when they appear during your development.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C++, [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/any.html) will let you do this in a type-safe way:

```
void func(boost::any const &x)
{
    // any_cast a reference and it
    // will throw if x is not an int.
    int i = any_cast<int>(x);

    // any_cast a pointer and it will
    // return a null pointer if x is not an int.
    int const *p = any_cast<int>(&x);
}

// pass in whatever you want.
func(123);
func("123");
```

In C, you would use a void pointer:

```
void func(void const *x)
{
    // it's up to you to ensure x points to an int.  if
    // it's not, it might crash or it might silently appear
    // to work. nothing is checked for you!
    int i = *(int const*)x;
}

// pass in whatever you want.

int i = 123;
func(&i);

func("123");
```

You seem adverse to it but I'll recommend it anyway: if you're using C++, embrace it.  Don't be afraid of templates.  Things like Boost.Any and void pointers have a place in C++, but it is very small.

**Update**:

> Well , I am making a small signals - slots - connections library to be
>   used with my gui toolkit. So that I can get rid of the Ugly WNDPROC. I
>   need these pointers for the connections.

If you need multi-target signals, [Boost.Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/signals.html) already provides a full and tested signals/slots implementation.  You can use [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bind) (or `std::bind`, if you've got a C++0x compiler) to connect member functions:

```
struct button
{
    boost::signal<void(button&)> on_click;
}

struct my_window
{
    button b;

    my_window()
    {
        b.on_click.connect(std::bind(&my_window::handle_click,
                                     this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }

    void handle_click(button &b)
    {
    }

    void simulate_click()
    {
        b.on_click(b);
    }
};
```

If you only want a simple callback, [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/function.html) (or `std::function` if you've got a C++0x compiler) will work well:

```
struct button
{
    std::function<void(button&)> on_click;
}

struct my_window
{
    button b;

    my_window()
    {
        b.on_click = std::bind(&my_window::handle_click,
                               this, std::placeholders::_1);
    }

    void handle_click(button &b)
    {
    }

    void simulate_click()
    {
        b.on_click(b);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a function that takes a `void*`, but you must be aware of the pointer types that are not compatible with `void*`:

- pointers to functions:

  ```
  void MyFunc(void*);

  MyFunc(&MyFunc); // WRONG
  ```
- pointers to members:

  ```
  void MyFunc(void*);

  struct A { int x; };

  MyFunc(&A::x); // WRONG
  ```

While these pointers are not compatible with `void*` (even with casting, on some compilers), they are themselves data.  So you can pass a pointer to the pointer:

```
void MyFunc(void*);

void (*pfn)(void*) = &MyFunc;
MyFunc(&pfn); // ok

struct A { int x; };
int A::*px = &A::x;
MyFunc(&px); // ok
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define the method as taking one `void *` argument. Of course, at that point, it's up to you to figure out what to do with the data (as far as accessing it or casting it.)

```
void MyFunc(void * ptr);
```

Comment: will i then need to cast every pointer? Like `MyFunc((void*) myptr);` ?

Comment: Depending on your compiler and options, no. Most compilers will let pointer conversion to `void *` slide. It may generate a warning or an error, but again, your mileage may vary.

Comment: @Adam : Implicit conversions of any pointer type to `void*` are guaranteed by the standard. If any compiler generates a warning or error, those compilers are broken.

Comment: @ildjarn: Almost.  All types of pointers to objects implicitly convert to `void*`.  But pointers to functions and pointers to members do not, and are in fact not compatible with `void*`.

Comment: @BenVoigt : Right, so for every pointer type with which it is legal to call this function, the pointer type is guaranteed to be implicitly convertible to `void*`; for every pointer type with which it is not legal to call this function, explicit casting wouldn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
void MyFunc( void* p){}

int g = 10;
MyFunc( (void*)&g );
```

Comment: will i then need to recast it to **int** inside the function?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: better safe than sorry

Comment: I believe to recast: int x = *(int *)p

Comment: @Dave: Better safe than sorry, yes.  Casting is not safe.  Doing it will someday make you sorry.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: a bit OT, but would be interested to know why casting is not safe in this instance, any references you can point me to?

Comment: @Dave: In this particular instance, it doesn't do anything at all, not unsafe, but also not useful.  But say in the future the program changes and it becomes `int g();`.  If you had no cast, the compiler would let you know you have a problem.  But with the cast, there will be no error and no warning, but undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`void *` is the way to do it. You can assign any pointer type to and from a `void *`. But to use the pointer in the called function, you'll have to know the type so you can create an appropriate local pointer or cast appropriately. You can encode a limited set of types as enum symbols, and perhaps use a switch to select type-specific behavior. But without a specific purpose or use-case, you might end up chasing your tail in a quest for generality for which C was never intended.

Another way would be to make a union to contain all the various types you *know are needed*.

```
typedef union {
    int i;
    char c;
    float f;
} vartype;
```

Then if the value can carry around its own type-identifier, it becomes a tag-union or variant-record.

```
typedef struct {
    enum type { INT, CHAR, FLOAT } type;
    vartype var;
} varrec;
```